# How to handle pop up window in appium with webdriver

Tags: android, testing, mobile, selenium-webdriver, appium

I unable to click Open button and getting an exception as "No such element exception". I tried all XPath and id but same exception I am getting. I have tried getContextHandles() and it returns size as one. it means control cannot switch. Kindly help me to click the "Open" button.

Below are the xPath i tried.

```
By.name("Open");
By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='1']");
By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='org.hola:id/btn_open']");
By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='org.hola:id/btn_open' and @index='1' and @text='Open']");
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this popup is coming after launching any app then you have to set the "appActivity" and "appPackage" capability in your code.

Comment: We have given appActivity and app package for launching Hola app. Napster is the app which can access only on US server hence we use Hola app to open this particular app. Hola app is listing out all the application and once we click Napster app we are getting new window/pop up. We unable to handle this new window/pop up.

Comment: In that case try to give "appActivity" and "appPackage" capability for Napster app.

Comment: I need to click "Open" button so that Napster app will access US server and work. If I open the app through appActivity and appPackage then Napster app will open with Indian server access and won't work. Is there any way to handle Open button

Comment: Please add the xpath or id which you are using to click the open button and also add the UIAutomator screenshot for the given popup window.

Comment: Try this one   driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//android.widget.Button[contains(@text,"Open")]")).click()

Answer (score 0):

Try MobileBy instead of By

```
MobileBy.name("Open");
MobileBy.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='1']");
MobileBy.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='org.hola:id/btn_open']");
MobileBy.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='org.hola:id/btn_open' and @index='1' and @text='Open']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Locator can be identified by using **UIAutomator viewer** tool. Following code setup use to handles the pop-up window in Appium

```
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
static void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "Android-version"); 
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "connected device name");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "App package name");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "App activity");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap); 
}
@Test
static void Selendroid() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Locator")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.findElementById("android:id/message").getText());
    driver.findElement(By.name("Locator")).click();
}
```

For Browser alerts use `driver.switchTo().alert()` method to Handle